Will spark split a groupby stage into load each group into memory one by one to reduce memory usage?
I have a table with pk date and user_id.
df = (
    spark.read.format("jdbc")
    .option("driver", driver)
    .option("url", url)
    .option("dbtable", table)
    .option("user", user)
    .option("password", password)
    .load()
)

df_ret = df.groupby(df.user_id, df.date).agg({"value": "sum"}).sort("date")

df_ret.take(10)

I found it takes long long time just like spark load the whole table into memory.
How can I let spark do the job one by one or at least dozen by dozen?

Right now you do the load on the full table and do a groupby, which means that it has to go over all data and therefore load all. You can remove the dbtable option and add the following for running a query on the original database:
.option("query", f"SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {table}")

In this case, your database should run the query and not spark. Note that this only selects the top 10 and doesn't do any groupby yet. If you need the full groupby, you could go for doing the groupby in the query, but that depends on the capacity of your engine and the size of your dataset whether that's feasible.

It seems no different with loop all days and users and generate sql for each group then calc my custom agg function by pandas. If spark load all data into memory, why people need it? Do I miss config it?

It doesn't always load all data into memory. However, you have data in a database. That means that if you want to do some operation, there should be some engine that runs it. So if you group by a dataset and do a sum, then all rows should be checked for the groupby column and for the column you're summing over. Either spark needs to do it (means all data accessible to spark) or your database engine. If you already have the data for example in delta format in your environment, it's a columnar store (parquet), meaning only those relevant column can ben accessed efficiently by spark.

The excepted behavior is  data sorted by date and user_id in database and stream to spark then calculated by each group. How can I config to do this? Just use sql query with order by?

If I create the plan manually, I'll fetch data sorted by date and read from stream into buffer until a new date value, then run agg function on rows with same day. No need to load all rows into memory. Can spark do this automatically?
